# How to hold on to a Simple XML object Variable

Tags: php, drupal

I am getting response from service as a simple xml object of form

```
Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [link] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [0] => LINK
                        )

                    [snippet] => Teaser 
                    [fragment] => foo
```

I tried assigning this to a session variable, cache table(drupal) global variable , but am not able to get the actual object later, I get empty values or invalid object.

Comment: Could you show us the code you use to assign the above to a session variable. Have you called `session_start()`?

Comment: I am using drupal, so session_start() will be taken care of.

Comment: It is still necessary that you show us the relevant pieces of your code so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) when assigning the xml variable to your session, then [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) at the other end.